# iOS 13 dark mode: UIColor.link too dark when used for NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, ios-darkmode

with iOS 13 dark mode, I use `UIColor.link` for two cases:

- foregroundColor color for `NSAttributedString`
- tint color for icons

problem: though I use `UIColor.link` in both cases, they render as different colors. 
The color rendered for `NSAttributedString` is darker and I find this color really hard to read over a black background.

code for `NSAttributedString`

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    linkAttributes[.foregroundColor] = UIColor.link
} else {
    linkAttributes[.foregroundColor] = UIColor.blue
}
// .font is the only other attribute I set
let attStr = NSAttributedString(string: cardName, attributes: linkAttributes)
```

I use this attributed string in a UIButton subclass that I instantiate programmatically:

```
class ConditionButton: UIButton {
    required init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        configureOnce()
    }

    func configureOnce() {
        self.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        self.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        self.titleLabel?.font = labelFont
        self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    }

    // some more code that does self.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
}
```

The text at the top is a hard to read label of a subclass of `UIButton` with `NSAttributedString`, at the bottom, there is an easy to read `UIButton` with an image and `tintColor = UIColor.link`

[image]

Why is that and how can I get the same readable color for `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't look like the `link` color at all. Are you sure there are no other attributes applied to the label (like transparency)? Maybe inspect it at runtime?

Comment: Edit: .font is the only other attribute I set. I'll check the label

Comment: What is rendered might be the link color for the light mode

Comment: No, it's much darker. Yours is `#1120D8`, the `link` system color is `#0079FF`.

Comment: I added code how I use the attributdString

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of...

**My mistake:**

When I asked the question, I did not notice, that I had the following line in my code:

```
linkAttributes[.link] = url
```

I don't need this attribute any more, since I us a button now.

**Bug in `NSAttributedString`:**

When using

```
linkAttributes[.link] = url
```

in an `NSAttributedString`, Apple overrides the color with a dark blue that was ok until `iOS 12`.

It appears, Apple has forgotten to use `UIColor.link` for links in `NSAttributedString`.

So, everybody who uses the `.link` attribute in dark mode will produce this unreadable dark blue color.

I'll file a radar after writing this answer.